# Custom dependency property not working in UWP template with TemplatedParent

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have the following DataTemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="5"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="{Binding ActualText}"
                       TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />                
            <my:CustomSelector Grid.Column="1"
                                         ActualValue="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbox"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Width="90"
                      Margin="3"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Value,
                                              Mode=TwoWay}" />

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is its code-behind file:

```
public sealed partial class CustomSelector : StackPanel
  {
    public int ActualValue
    {
      get { return (int)GetValue(ActualValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ActualValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ActualValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyActualValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActualValue", typeof(int), typeof(CustomSelector), new PropertyMetadata(0, (x, y) =>
        {
          CustomSelector cc = x as CustomSelector;
          int content = (int)y.NewValue;
          cc.ActualValue = content;
        }));


    public CustomSelector()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
    } 
  }
```

The binding in the `TextBlock` and `ComboBox` works okay so the DataContext is correct.

I learned that *custom bindings* in templates work only if the `RelativeSource` is set to `TemplatedParent`.

Unfortunately my custom control's `ActualValue` property is always set to its default (which is clearly wrong) and when I change the value, it always starts from 0.

What else could I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake and overwritten the ***DataContext*** of my custom control so it couldn't find the `Value` property inside its context.

So, I removed the following line:

```
 DataContext = this;
```

Now it works as expected.